# 1064 Sql syntax error in Mysql query

Tags: mysql

I got error of sql syntax in Mysql. Where am I wrong?
My query is,

```
SELECT *
FROM `fx_users_attendance`
   LEFT OUTER JOIN `fx_account_details` ON fx_account_details.user_id = fx_users_attendance.user_id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN `fx_departments` ON fx_departments.deptid = fx_account_details.department
   LEFT OUTER JOIN `fx_users` ON fx_users.id = fx_users_attendance.user_id
WHERE fx_departments.deptid IN("1")
      AND fx_users.id ="5"
      AND date(fx_users_attendance.clock_in) BETWEEN (date(fx_users_attendance.clock_in) >= "2015-10-20"
      AND date(fx_users_attendance.clock_in) <= "2015-11-10")
```

Comment: Can you post the error you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss understood the syntax of `BETWEEN`

### `date(fx_users_attendance.clock_in) BETWEEN (date(fx_users_attendance.clock_in) >= "2015-10-20" AND date(fx_users_attendance.clock_in) <= "2015-11-10")`

Should be changed to

### `date(fx_users_attendance.clock_in) BETWEEN '2015-10-20' AND '2015-11-10'`

```
SELECT * 
FROM `fx_users_attendance`
 LEFT OUTER JOIN `fx_account_details` ON fx_account_details.user_id = fx_users_attendance.user_id 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN `fx_departments` ON fx_departments.deptid = fx_account_details.department 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN `fx_users` ON fx_users.id = fx_users_attendance.user_id 
 WHERE fx_departments.deptid IN("1") AND fx_users.id ="5" AND date(fx_users_attendance.clock_in) BETWEEN '2015-10-20' AND '2015-11-10'
```

Hope this helps.